How to add Content-Type header in custom send port
We are using Biztalk 2016 and configured WCF-Custom Sendport to send SOAP messages. We require to set following Content-Type:
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; action="actioname"; charset=UTF-8

string headerString = "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; action=\"actioname\"; charset=UTF-8";
pInMsg.Context.Write("HttpHeaders", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/01/Adapters/WCF-properties", headerString);
pInMsg.Context.Promote("IsDynamicSend", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties", true);

With this code, Content-Type header is not being added to outgoing request.

Your variable naming seems to imply that it is an inbound message, rather than an outbound one. Have you tried attaching Visual Studio to the BizTalk Host instance process and debugging?

where you added this code? pipeline or custom behavior? I suggest you to use the WCF-WebHttp not the WCF-Custom. Have a look at this blog post:
https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-httpheaders-with-wcf-webhttp-adapter-on-biztalk-2013/?country_sel=fr

The approach you're using to set the Content-Type header is correct in principle. Writing to the "HttpHeaders" context property should allow you to set custom HTTP headers.
However, there are a few potential issues that could prevent this from working:
a. The property name "HttpHeaders" is case-sensitive. Make sure it's exactly as shown.
b. The namespace URI must be correct. The one you're using looks right, but double-check it.
c. The format of the header string is important. Each header should be on a separate line, ending with a CRLF (\r\n).
Another approach is to set these properties in the WCF-Custom adapter configuration:

In the send port configuration, go to the "Messages" tab. Set
"Message body" to "Raw". Set "Content type" to
"application/soap+xml". In the "Outbound HTTP headers" section, add a
new header: Name: SOAPAction Value: actioname


I again checked all above points but still its not added. Here please note that I am using WCF-Custom sendport and custom binding.
